# g sensor not working at all

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sensors

I have an Asus memo pad, All of the sudden its g sensor stop working, I tried `accelerometer` and `bubble`, they show that g sensor not working at all.

any help?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, according to [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2216224), I turned off auto rotate and turned off tablet for about ten minutes, then turn it on again and now g sensor works!